# getting 502 bad gateway iin openshift route

Tags: kubernetes, routes, openshift, okd

Hi today when I try to expose my service using route I'm getting 502 bad gateway...my openshift cluster version is 3.11. I used oc expose my-service to expose my service using the route. I have described my route below.

```
Name:         hello-world
Namespace:    uvindu-k8soperator
Labels:       app=hello-world
Annotations:  openshift.io/host.generated: true
API Version:  route.openshift.io/v1
Kind:         Route
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2020-03-31T05:45:05Z
  Resource Version:    15860504
  Self Link:           /apis/route.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/uvindu-k8soperator/routes/hello-world
  UID:                 c5e6e8cc-7312-11ea-b6ad-fa163e41f92e
Spec:
  Host:  hello-world-uvindu-k8soperator.apps.novalocal
  Port:
    Target Port:  port-9095
  To:
    Kind:           Service
    Name:           hello-world
    Weight:         100
  Wildcard Policy:  None
Status:
  Ingress:
    Conditions:
      Last Transition Time:  2020-03-31T05:45:05Z
      Status:                True
      Type:                  Admitted
    Host:                    hello-world-uvindu-k8soperator.apps.novalocal
    Router Name:             router
    Wildcard Policy:         None
Events:                      <none>
```

Comment: if you go into your pod and curl the server url, does it respond? 
Does your application respond on localhost in the pod?

Comment: @ChrisBolton I am facing the same issue and the application respond properly with service url and port and the same 502 error I am facing with curl and route url.

Comment: @uvindusri Did you resolve the issue?